# Send Json Object to Spring Controller

Tags: json, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

Hy guys.

I have this js code, where I create an object to send to a Spring controller via Ajax function:

```
$('#eventsdatageneral').on('click', '.btn.btn-info', function(event) 
            {
                var today_date = new Date().getTime(); 
                var dataToSend = new Object();
                dataToSend.dateToSend = today_date;
                dataToSend.nameToSend = host_name;
                dataToSend.typeToSend = type_name;
                console.log(dataToSend);
                event.preventDefault();

                //here starts the code to sending data to Spring controller
                $.ajax({
                        url: "../todaydatarecover.json",
                        type: "post",
                        data: dataToSend,
                        success : function() {

                            console.log("Invio riuscito.");
                            //console.log(moment(today_date).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
                        }

                    });
            });
```

This is the controller:

```
@PostMapping(value="/todaydatarecover.json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView todayInfoAndIdRecover(ModelAndView model, HttpServletRequest request,
            @RequestParam(name="dateToSend", required=false) long dateInBox,
            @RequestParam(name="nameToSend", required=false) String nameInBox,
            @RequestParam(name="typeToSend", required=false) String typeInBox) throws IOException
    {
        //First of all, we invoke getinfo methods to take info and id
        Timestamp date = new Timestamp(dateInBox); 
        Events event = networks.getInfoandId(nameInBox, typeInBox, date);

        //Second, we put this list in the model and set properties for jquery datatables
        model.addObject("data", event);

        //Verify id and info
        System.out.println("The info is: " + event.getInfo());
        System.out.println("The id is: " + event.getId());   

        //Finally, we return the model
        return model;
    }
```

When I try to execute, i got an `org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessExceptionIncorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0`; but, if  I query the DB via MySQL client, i can take the correct result without problems. So, there is a row that match the query I perform; this make me think that the problem is how I create the Json Object and/or I send it to Controller.

What's my error?

Comment: When sending informations with `data`, it's in the request's body, you can't retrieve your data with `@RequestParam`. You need to use `@RequestBody` and create and object with your three variables. Ex : `...todayInfoAndIdRecover(@RequestBody TodayData todayData...`.

Comment: Do you need `POST` or need `GET`? You are sending the request in the body from `AJAX` and then you are using `@ReqeustParam` in the server side. This doesn't work. If you want to use `GET` then it can be possible.

Comment: @Rossi Robinson I need Post.

Comment: Then change the Spring controller method to have `@RequestBody`. Look for some examples how you can do it.

Comment: @Thoomas thanks. Your solution makes better my scenario; I got a 404 error but no longer the EmptyResultsException.

Comment: @LucaSepe You're welcome. When are you getting your 404 ? when posting to `/todaydatarecover.json` ?

Comment: @Thoomas yes. But I got the reason: bad use of RequestBody annotation. Now I search the correct use to fix the problem. Again, thanks for the response.

Comment: @LucaSepe Ok, if you need our help, provide more details or post another question if it's completely different. I'll post my comment as an answer because it has helped you solving your (first) problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending informations with data, it's in the request's body, you can't retrieve your data with `@RequestParam`. You need to use `@RequestBody` and create and object with your three variables.

Example :

```
@PostMapping(value="/todaydatarecover.json")
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView todayInfoAndIdRecover(@RequestBody TodayData todayData, ModelAndView model, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException
{
```